# Filtering in VBA in excel and is there a way to better optimize it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that I got from recording a macro but I find it to be a bit slow or maybe that is the way it is supposed to be not sure.  I read somewhere that the way macros are recorded may not be the most efficient way and hence the reason for my question

```
Sub CareFilter()

Sheets("Main").Select
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AX$10000").AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "LATE", "LATP/F", "PAY-"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$M$1:$M$10000").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "ATHRLE", "ATOCEE", "ATOCSE", "ATWCBC", "ATWCBE", "ATWCSE", "BLBSGE", "BLWCCE", _
    "BRBESE", "BRBSAB", "BRBSAE", "BRBSGE", "BRBWRE", "BRCBSE", "BRCCBE", "BRCCCE", _
    "BRCIS1", "BRCISE", "BROCSE", "BRSCBE", "BRWBSE", "BRWCBE", "BUBSGE", "BUOCBX", _
    "BUOCSE", "BUWCBE", "BUWCSE", "HMCCBE", "KTCCBE", "KTCCOE", "KTCTCE", "KTMCCE", _
    "KTOCE2", "KTOCE3", "KTOCEE", "KTPRSE", "KTRMTE", "KTSDCE", "KTSOOE", "KTWCSE", _
    "MNATCE", "MNATRE", "MNCCOE", "MNHRLE", "MNMCCE", "MNPSSE", "MTBESB", "MTBSAB", _
    "MTBSGB", "MTBSMB", "MTCBSB", "MTCHDB", "MTCTCB", "MTOCEB", "MTSCBB", "MTWBEB", _
    "MTWBLB", "MTWBSB", "MTWCBB", "MTWCCB", "MTWCSB", "OTCIS1", "OTCISE", "OTOCSE", _
    "OTSCBE", "OTSCSB", "OTWCBE", "PKCCBE", "PKCHDE", "PKHRLE", "PKLCBE", "PKLWBE", _
    "PKOCSE", "PKPRIE", "PKPRSE", "PKSCBE", "PKWCBE", "PKWCSE", "YMBSAB", "YMBSAE", _
    "YMBWRE"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AW$10000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AW$10000").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "AWOL", "LATE", "LATF", "LATP", "OVAB", "PAY-"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BD$10000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=">" & 1 / 10 ^ 10
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

The macro does exactly what I need it to do just hoping there may be a quicker way to achieve the same results.  I do have a few of these macros that are doing different things.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be greatly helpful if you explained what the macro actually does.

Comment: You're using the `.AutoFilter` built in function. I'm not sure you're going to get it much faster than that. The only thing I think that's slowing you down is the large list of character strings that you're filtering out of your 10000 row result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Filter is going to always filter on the same set of values then put them in a list on a separate worksheet. (I like the name Lookups)
Add a column to your sheet that you want to filter on and add the Match function to lookup the same value on the Lookups tab. Match will return either the number of the row it finds the matching value or a #N/A indicating no match. Wrap the Match function in an if statement to return a true/false, (or 0,1) and name the column QuickFilter. Extend the Autofilter to include the new column then select True as the choice.  After you have it working for filtering on the toughest column repeat the process for the other columns.

The match function would look like this:

```
=if(isna(Match('Lookups'!A1,"$M$1:$M$10000",0),"",True))
```

Since you are doing multiple column combinations you could use a 0, 1 for false, true respectively, then add similar formulas for the other search criteria.

So the formula would be if criteria column 1 matches then 1 PLUS if criteria column 2 matches then 1.... Only filter the values that add up to 5.

It is all formula based, but can be automated to auto populate the columns once the formulas are tested.

Reply back if this is making sense and you require additional help.